# mongodb and php cant install driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I need help installing the driver so I can use the mongo database in php.
 This is what I have done so far:

```
I installed php and am using the built in webserver
I installed mongodb
I added the driver from https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html
in to my ext php folder
I added
[Mongo]
extension=php_mongo.dll
in my php.ini file
```

I did everything right, but it will not load the module.
did I miss something?

I found it is not loading it because `phpinfo()` does not show it.

Comment: Did you restart the web server? Are you using Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I restarted the server. I am using the built in php server. the one that the php installation comes with

Comment: Make a file with `phpinfo();` in it and take a look to see if the extention is working properly, if not maybe you'll need another library, and you should try with another one.

Comment: it is not loaded properly that is the problem. I have tried many different versions as well

Comment: I assume you are using windows, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the wrong extension on the mongodb driver, you could check that in [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/) to see wich version of mongodb driver correspond to your PHP version, once you've done that, if you're using windows, you need to tell PHP to use the extension modifying the php.ini file adding the extension like this

[image: Modifying the php.ini file]

Finally you'll need to restart your web server (apache or nginx) so you can use that extension, you verify that making a file with `phpinfo();` in it and it should show something like this, if it does then you're ready to go

[image: Mongo extension]